# swashbuckle openapi 3 write example and description for the dynamically generated model classes

Tags: openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

My model properties definition is coming from a json file so using reflection to write the classes to be shown under schema on resulting swagger page.

```
foreach (var model in Models)
            {
                if (!ModelTypes.ContainsKey(model.Key))
                {
                    anyNonCompiledModel = true;
                    BuildModelCodeClass(modelComponentBuilder, model.Value);//Build model classes
                }
            }
            BuildModelCodeEnd(modelComponentBuilder);

            if (anyNonCompiledModel)
            {
                CSharpCompiler compiler = new CSharpCompiler();
                compiler.AddReference(typeof(object));
                compiler.AddReference(typeof(ResourceFactory));
                compiler.AddReference(typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver));
                compiler.AddReference(typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute));
                var types = compiler.Compiler(modelComponentBuilder.ToString()); //write model classes

                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    ModelTypes.Add(type.Name, type);
                }
            }

public void BuildModelCodeClass(StringBuilder modelComponentBuilder, MetadataModelEntity model)
        {
            
            modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine($"public class {model.Name} {{");

            foreach (var p in model.Data.Properties)
            {
                if (p.Obsoleted) continue;

                if (p.Type.Type == "array")
                {
                    modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine($" public {p.Type.ArrayType.ObjectName}[] {p.Name} {{get;set;}}");
                }
                else
                {
                    //primitive types
                    modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine($" public {p.Type.ObjectName} {p.Name} {{get;set;}}");
                }
            }
            modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine(
@"}
");
            
        }
```

If i provide the description and example like following (in BuildModelCodeClass, inside the loop) then the example and description displays for me.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)p.Example))
                {
                    modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine($" ///<example>{p.Example}</example>");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)p.Description))
                {
                    modelComponentBuilder.AppendLine($" ///<description>{p.Description}</description>");
                }
```

However, i dont want to do above.

1. I want to write my models via the open api and not via the C# Compiler, is it possible?
2. I want to show example and description via schema (may be under paths some where). How can i do this? Context has my models info available that i can interact with here.

   public class SwaggerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
   {
   SwaggerDocument _swaggerDocument;
   public SwaggerDocumentFilter(object apiConfigure)
   {
   _swaggerDocument = ((ApiGatewayConfiguration)apiConfigure).SwaggerDocument;
   }

   ```
       public void Apply(OpenApiDocument document, DocumentFilterContext context)
       {
           if (document.Info.Extensions == null || !document.Info.Extensions.ContainsKey(SwaggerEndpoint.ExtensionDocName)) return;

           var openIdString = document.Info.Extensions[SwaggerEndpoint.ExtensionDocName] as OpenApiString;
           if (openIdString == null) return;

           var docName = openIdString.Value;

           SwaggerEndpoint endpoint = _swaggerDocument.SwaggerEndpoints.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == docName);
           if (endpoint == null) return;


           //Add server objects
           document.Servers = endpoint.ServerObjects;

           //Add Tags objects
           document.Tags = endpoint.Tags;

           //Set swagger paths objects

           var pathsObjects = _swaggerDocument.GetPathsObject(docName, context);
           if (pathsObjects.IsValid())
           {
               pathsObjects.ToList().ForEach(
                   item => document.Paths.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
                   );
           }

           //Add Schema components
           //Add Example/Examples
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Following helped
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/162

AddSchemaExamples.cs

```
public class AddSchemaExamples : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Product))
        {
            schema.example = new Product
                {
                    Id = 123,
                    Type = ProductType.Book,
                    Description = "Treasure Island",
                    UnitPrice = 10.0M
                };
        }
    }
}
```

SwaggerConfig.cs

```
httpConfig 
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
         {
             c.SchemaFilter<AddSchemaExamples>()
         });
```

My implementation for the Apply since model is dynamic

```
if (model != null)
                {
                    schema.Description = model.Description;
                    foreach (var p in schema.Properties)
                    {
                        var mp = model.Data.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == p.Key);
                        if (mp != null)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mp.Description))
                            {
                                p.Value.Description = mp.Description;
                            }
                            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mp.Example))
                            {
                                p.Value.Example =
                                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString(mp.Example.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```